# : not a valid identifier bash export says

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, hadoop

I am trying to run hadoop .I tried these steps     -bash: export: `HADOOP_OPTS-Djava.library.path=/home/hdoop/hadoop-3.2.1/lib/nativ': not a valid identifier

followed this steps..

https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-hadoop-ubuntu

on running `source ~/.bashrc` getting following error

Answer (score 17):

You're missing the `=` character between the variable name and its value:

```
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/nativ"
# Here -----------^
```

Comment: The linked page has this typo so no wonder the OP made this error.

Comment: Also should be "native" rather than "nativ"